# xsd:list of custom type is generated into List<String>

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

We have an xsd schema with a declaration like this:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="customId">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:appinfo>
            <jaxb:javaType name="com.company.identifiers.CustomId" parseMethod="fromString" printMethod="toString"/>
        </xsd:appinfo>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:int" />
</xsd:simpleType>
```

Then, I want to have a list of this type in a generated Java class:

```
<xsd:complexType name="SomeMessage">
    ...
<xsd:attribute name="customIds" use="optional">
        <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:list itemType="customId" />
        </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:attribute>
    ...
</xsd:complexType>
```

But the field `customIds`, for some reason, is generated as `List<String>`.

I guess, `xsd:sequence` could be used instead of `xsd:list`, but `SomeMessage` already has an `xsd:choice`, and as far as I get, it is illegal to have `xsd:sequence` in the same declaration.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code generated using NetBeans 7.1.2, running on Java 1.7.0_02.

If you want to map simple types to Java classes, one way to do is to globally set `mapSimpleTypeDef="true"`

```
<xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:appinfo>
        <jaxb:globalBindings mapSimpleTypeDef="true"/>
    </xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
```

Generated code:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "SomeMessage")
public class SomeMessage {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "customIds")
    protected List<CustomId> customIds;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the customIds property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
     * {@link CustomId }
     * 
     * 
     */
    public List<CustomId> getCustomIds() {
        if (customIds == null) {
            customIds = new ArrayList<CustomId>();
        }
        return this.customIds;
    }

}
```

If you want to refer your pre-existing CustomId class, then the following works in my case:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="customId">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:int"/>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:complexType name="SomeMessage">
    <xsd:attribute name="customIds" use="optional">
        <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:appinfo>
                    <jaxb:javaType name="java.util.List&lt;com.company.identifiers.CustomId>" parseMethod="Class1.fromString" printMethod="Class1.toString"/>
                </xsd:appinfo>
            </xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:list itemType="customId"/>
        </xsd:simpleType>
    </xsd:attribute>
</xsd:complexType>
```

You'll get the following:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "SomeMessage")
public class SomeMessage {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "customIds")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(Adapter1 .class)
    protected List<CustomId> customIds;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the customIds property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public List<CustomId> getCustomIds() {
        return customIds;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the customIds property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setCustomIds(List<CustomId> value) {
        this.customIds = value;
    }

}
```

And the generated Adapter1:

```
public class Adapter1
    extends XmlAdapter<String, List<CustomId>>
{


    public List<CustomId> unmarshal(String value) {
        return (Class1.fromString(value));
    }

    public String marshal(List<CustomId> value) {
        return (Class1.toString(value));
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Actually, I'm trying to get not a `List<Integer>`, but a `List<CustomId>`. I'm using JAXB 2.2.

Comment: As for `xsd:sequence` and `xsd:choice`, I mean the following:
`<xsd:complexType name="SomeMessage">
    <xsd:choice> ... </xsd:choice>
    <xsd:sequence><attribute name="customIds" type="customId"/></xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>`
For this kind of declaration, it says "Element 'sequence' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.".

Comment: I've updated to deal with your clarifications. To have a choice and a sequence, you need a sequence wrapper like so: <sequence><choice>...</choice><sequence>...</sequence></sequence>. Attributes cannot be placed inside a model group (sequence/choice/all), they live outside it. If you want to use elements instead of an attribute based on an xsd:list, then you would use the nested sequence in my example to implement it.

Comment: Thank you again! The solution with fully-qualified type `"java.util.List&lt;com.company.identifiers.CustomId>"` solved my problem. Now I have `List<CustomId>`.